# The activists' energetic work in the service of both woman suffrage.. __ the assertion that the two movements were ___

Tags: word-choice, sentence

> The activists' energetic work in the service of both woman suffrage
>   and the temperance movement in the late nineteenth century (i) ____
>   the assertion that the two movements were (ii)___.

The activists have done 'energetic' work for the two movements. This implies that the two movements must have been prevalent during that time. 
Hence, the 'energetic' work must must support this assertion.

Hence, the word choices for (i) and (ii) should be **supports** and **predominant** respectively.

But I found this wrong when given the following choices:

> > (i) undermines; supports; underscores  (ii) diffuse; inimical; predominant

'underscores' is not a good fit for the first blank for it is meant to lay emphasis on a specific part of a sentence or point.

'undermines' doesn't play well either with the other choices for the second blank.

'diffuse' for (ii) is also close for it denotes 'spreading through' but I think predominant is more appropriate in terms of the movements.

'inimical' meaning 'not friendly' doesn't make any sense. What would it mean to say that the movements were not friendly?

I am a little confused here. Please help!

Comment: How do you mean you found it wrong when given the options? Do you mean that you had answered _supports_ and _predominant_, but when you got the results back, that was marked as being an incorrect answer? Also, is this all the context there is? From the question itself as it stands, I can see no meaningful way of arriving at an answer. None of the options given makes any sense, basically.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, that is correct. And this is the complete question per se. There is no other accompanying context. And yes, the answer that I chose (as mentioned) are marked as wrong. I 'found it wrong' as the correct answer mentioned in the keys (that do not make sense to me) are (i) undermines, (ii) inimical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, this is not a very well-asked question. There isn’t sufficient context to make a properly informed choice and select a felicitous combination of answers.

*Undermines* and *inimical* are the only options that I can **kind of** see making sense, though they’re not really ideal.

Your error in choosing *supports* and *predominant* was assuming that the fact that activists worked energetically for the causes means the causes were prevalent—it doesn’t. You can work energetically for an obscure cause, too.

The fact that the (same) activists worked in **both** causes undermines the assertion that the two causes are inimical to each other: if suffrage and temperance had been causes that were diametrically opposed to each other, no activist would have worked energetically for both of them. It would have been one or the other.

I would argue, however, that the question’s use of *inimical* is highly unclear, because it doesn’t state what the causes are supposed to be inimical **to**. The default reading, at least to me, of a phrase like “The two causes were inimical” would be that they were both inimical to the same thing, most likely the government, some policy, etc. The question seems to assume that *inimical* on its own means *inimical to one another*, which I would disagree with.